# ”ないし”-Unable to understand the use of this phrase here

Tags: meaning, phrases

> 基底**ないし**パターンの数ｍは、5.3.3項で説明した方法を使ってデータごとに求めるべきパラメータです

I am unable to understand the use of "ないし" phrase in the head of the above sentence after the "基底". This phrase is a form of the adjective "ない", meaning no/is not, which is mainly used when the speaker wants to continue after the negation. So why is this being used in the head of the sentence ?

If necessary, this sentence is speaking about a machine learning algorithm and its tuning.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's the conjunction [乃至{ないし}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%B9%83%E8%87%B3-587098), meaning "or" here, and "from ... to" in other contexts.

> 基底**ないし**パターンの数ｍは…
>
> The (amount?) of bases **or** patterns, `m`, ...

Answer (score 7):

[ないし](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/162407/meaning/m0u/) is a conjunction that has two meanings:

1. range of numbers

   > 二年ないし三年 *from two to three years*; *two up to three years*
2. "and/or" with some nuance of "by extension", such as...

   > 母ないし親として *as a mother, or more generally, a parent*
   >   新幹線ないし特急で *by shinkansen or (if failed) express train*
   >   日本ないし韓国 *Japan, and (even) also Korea*

   I don't know what relation lies between 基底 "basis" and パターン "pattern" in your context, but logically it only means OR in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are studying something about DCT(discrete cosine transform).　
「基底ないしパターンの数ｍ」 means "m number of bases (plural form of basis) or patterns", and the meaning of 「ないし」 is "or" that is described in siikamiika's answer.