# How does one express uncertainty when describing numbers e.g. 170-odd cases

Tags: words, expressions, counters

I found myself stuttering when I tried to tell my boss that I had finished sending **a-hundred-some-odd** emails yesterday.

I've ask a similar question on HiNative a long time ago, and here I quote the answer I received:

> 十何人は10〜19人の間です
>
> 十数人はおおよそ10〜19人の間です
>
> 何十人は10〜99人までのことを言います

Following this logic, I reckon saying **百七十何通** might be it.
However, somehow this does not ring a bell at all.

Is there no equivalent to this expression in Japanese?

Comment: @naruto Seeing 170 in the title it's fair to assume he meant 百七十何通

Comment: @Christer Thanks, I've missed it.

Comment: 百七十数通送る / 百七十何通**か**送る. This difference of か is important. In the question form, 百七十何通か送りますか and 百七十何通送りますか have different meanings. The latter is a way of asking the exact volume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can say 百七十ちょい (very casual), 百七十ちょっと (casual), 百七十[あまり](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BD%99%E3%82%8A) and 百七十[強（きょう）](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BC%B7) (formal).
- You can also say 百七十幾つ（ひゃくななじゅういくつ） and 百七十幾ら（ひゃくななじゅういくら）, but you cannot use a counter (e.g., 通) with them.
- 百七十数通（ひゃくななじゅうすうつう） is also acceptable, but it's less common than the others presumably because 170 is already specific enough. 百数十通 is common (roughly between 110 and 190).
- Yet another way to say this is 百七、八十通（ひゃくしち・はちじゅっつう）. See: [What is the correct expression of 10/20, 20/30, 30/40 etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68582/5010)

Comment: Just to be sure, you meant saying 百七十強/百七十あまり/etc.通 is acceptable? (いつもお世話になっておりますナルトさん。)

Comment: @YetiApe Ah, they come after the count. 百七十通強, 百七十通あまり, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head,

約【やく】170

大雑把【おおざっぱ】に170くらい

170あまり　(implies slightly more than 170)

170弱【じゃく】　(implies slightly less than 170)

アバウト１７０　(just kidding)